# How can I publish grafana dashbord using API?

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I'm very new to grafana and I hope to use grafana API for uploading .json file to publish dashboard in grafana marketplace instead of uploading it manually. Are there any options or API can use for it?

Answer (score 0):

Share a dashboard via the share icon in the top nav. This opens the share dialog where you can get a link to the current dashboard with the current selected time range and template variables. If you have made changes to the dashboard, make sure those are saved before sending the link. Below are ways to share a dashboard.

You can publish snapshots to you local instance or to **snapshot.raintank.io**. The later is a free service that is provided by **Raintank** that allows you to publish dashboard snapshots to an external grafana instance. The same rules still apply, anyone with the link can view it. You can set an expiration time if you want the snapshot to be removed after a certain time period.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it worked now. But my intention is to upload a JSON file in Grafana Lab as a dashboard without doing manually bcz in here we have to click the upload button and upload the file. If I can use some command-line argument instead of UI to upload fie to publish dashboard.